# How To theme fields in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Using Drupal 8,  In a teaser mode, I've managed to get the data that I want to be displayed but the markup is different than what I want. how can I change the html generated for specific fields such as, [body] or [tags] using the theme function.

Comment: there are articles on theming out there. you should read them.

Answer (score 1):

First, goto your /sites/default/services.yml
And, under "twig.config", search for "debug: false"
Make it true, clear cache. Now, refresh your page.

Now, inspect your html or view its source. You will see the twig file path from where its theming/html is coming.

Just copy that file in your theme's template folder, and do changes accordingly.